# explain ackerman's recursion. how long it takes to execute the following code for an average PC

Tags: algorithms, programming-languages, recursion

how does  that recursion work

```
#include <stdio.h>


int ack(m,n)
int m,n;
{
int ans;
if (m == 0) ans = n+1;
else if (n == 0) ans = ack(m-1,1);
else ans = ack(m-1, ack(m,n-1));
return (ans);
}

int main (argc, argv)
int argc; char ** argv;

{ int i,j;
for (i=0; i<6; i++)
for (j=0;j<6; j++)

printf ("ackerman (%d,%d) is: %d\n",i,j, ack(i,j));
}
```

Comment: There's no need to include the code: Ackermann's function has a simple mathematical definition. As for the run time on an "average PC", you need to look at roughly how many instructions are executed when the program runs, and you may as well assume one instruction per clock cycle.

Answer (score 1):

[The Ackermann–Péter function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann%27s_function) works as advertised, while not being [primitive recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function). There is an abundance of literature on this function and its execution time. Growth in the second parameter depends on the first, it is a bit like going from counting to addition to multiplication to exponentiation ...
The execution time of the code shown is entirely irrelevant, as the values will almost immediately overflow anyways - *[googol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol)* is *small* compared to `ack(4,2)`, [googolplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googolplex) dwarfed by `ack(5, 1)`.